# My function isn't returning what I expect using higher order functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, higher-order-functions

I have an issue that I cannot figure out, here is my code:

```
var people = [
  {name: "Alyssa P. Hacker", age: 26},
  {name: "Ben Bitdiddle", age: 34},
  {name: "Eva Lu Ator", age: 19},
  {name: "Lem E. Tweakit", age: 40}
];

function map(arr, f){
  var finalArr = [];
  each(arr, function(arrI){
    finalArr.push(f(arrI))
  })
  return finalArr;
}

function mapNameAge(obj){
    for (var key in obj){
      return obj[key].name + " is " + obj[key].age;
    }
}

function mapArr(obj, f){
  return map(obj, mapNameAge);
}
```

As you can see in mapArr function, I'm trying to use map to push a string in to finalArr thhat contains indexes of ["Alyssa P. Hacker is 26", "Ben Bitdiddle is 34" and so on...]

If I run `mapNameAge(people)` in the console, it brings back Alyssa's information as expected. But when I run `mapArr(people, mapNameAge)` in the console, I get `["undefined is undefined", "undefined is undefined", "undefined is undefined", "undefined is undefined"]`

Can someone please help me understand what's going on here? TIA!

Comment: `obj[key].name` does not exist... You don't need the loop. `people.map(function(obj){return obj.name +' is '+ obj.age})`

Comment: Thanks! I think I got confused because this was the first thing I did to make it work: ```map(people, function(x){
  for(var key in people){
    return people[key].name;
}
})``` I typed that in to the console and it was working. I just wasn't sure why breaking up the two didn't work... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elclanrs is correct. Because you are passing in a single object, not an object of objects, you don't need to iterate through the object. What you are passing into mapNameAge(obj) is

```
{ name: 'Alyssa P. Hacker', age: 26 }
```

Because of this, in mapNameAge(obj), instead of iterating (which is why it is returning undefined, because obj[key].name doesn't exist), you can just do this:

```
function mapNameAge(obj) {
    return obj.name + " is " + obj.age;
}
```

Comment: That worked! I think I'm still struggling with understanding the higher level functions. Glad you guys can help!!